# Reading a matrix from a text file as RDD of vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a large matrix of doubles from a tab separated text file, row by row. This is in Scala/Apache Spark.

If I do the following:

val obs = sc.textFile("path_to_text_file")

I get obs: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

However, the requirement is to have an RDD of vectors. Would you kindly help?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Probably more info on what you have and what you want would help. (Separator character, is it row-wise or column-wise; RDD of vector of doubles, but row-wise, or column-wise?)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gábor. I edited the question accordingly...

Comment: More specifically, I get the following errors:

Comment: [error] .../test/src/main/scala/mult_gaus.scala:22: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work for you:

```
final val SEPARATOR_AS_REGEX = ";"//Replace it with your separator regex
obs.map(line => line.split(SEPARATOR_AS_REGEX).map(
    //Parse the individual elements
    arr => arr.map(s => parseDouble(s))
  ).map(ds => new DenseVector(ds)))//Convert to the expected type
```

Comment: Hey, do you know how to use this logic in pyspark? I want to create a RDD of vectors in pyspark to work on the multivariate statistical analysis part. Any suggestions?